# Executable jar can't find or load main class after it's created with a gradle task

Tags: gradle, gluon-mobile

I used the gluon plugin to create a new single view project and changed nothing in its files. If I use the gradle task `application > run` it works fine. But if I use the taks `build > jar` it created the jar under `SingleViewProject\build\libs` and when I run it from the command line i get

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication

This is the untouched build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.1.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.0.0'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

and the "main class":

```
package com.gluonapplication;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.Swatch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GluonApplication extends MobileApplication {

    public static final String BASIC_VIEW = HOME_VIEW;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        addViewFactory(BASIC_VIEW, () -> new BasicView(BASIC_VIEW));
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(Scene scene) {
        Swatch.BLUE.assignTo(scene);

        ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new Image(GluonApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
    }
}
```

It's true that there is no `main` method in the class but you shouldn't need one. And it runs fine straight from the IDE. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute the `jar` task on a Gluon project, you will get *just* a jar with the classes and resources under the main and desktop packages of your project. In your case, something like this:

[image]

That jar contains the main class, but it doesn't contain any of the dependencies (Gluon Charm).

If you want to create an executable jar, you need to create a `shadowJar` or `fatJar`, that bundles all the dependencies within that jar.

You can add this plugin for it: `com.github.johnrengelman.shadow`, based on this [project](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).

Once you add the plugin, all you need to do is let it know about your custom configurations, as it doesn't know about the Desktop one.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.1'
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

...

// Add desktop dependencies to the task
shadowJar {
    configurations = [project.configurations.desktopRuntime]
}
```

Reload your project and execute `shadowJar`. You can find it under the Tasks menu:

[image]

You will find your executable jar under /builds/libs/yourProjectName-all.jar.

[image]

Comment: cool. can you help me "Add the plugin"? do i checkout the project and built a jar, then include it?

Comment: I just did... the code I posted already includes all you need to do: adding a plugin requires only referring the dependency and using `apply plugin...`. Gradle manages that for you.

Comment: ah, great! thanks. i would also add to the answer that the gradle task to build the shadow jar is under `projectName/shadow/shadowJar` if anyone will still be looking under `build`.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the answer with a screenshot of the Tasks menu. The `shadow` submenu appears if you have several `shadow*` tasks.