# compile and build gluon mobile app for desktop

Tags: javafxports, gluon-mobile

we have

```
desktopRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.15.1'
```

in gradle file.
i build project but my zip file dont have this file in lib folder.
how can i build project for desktop?
my ide is netbeans.
Thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the `distZip` or `jar` gradle tasks is they miss to include desktop dependencies.

When deploying to desktop you can change temporary `desktopRuntime` to `runtime`, so they will be included, as Ladislav Török suggests, but then you should undo the change so that dependency isn't included in the mobile deployment.

If you want to have a working zip, we have to modify the `distZip` task, to include the desktop dependencies in the lib folder, and also to include them in the class path (so they are also added to the scripts in the bin folder). Include this in your `build.gradle` script:

```
startScripts {
    classpath += configurations.desktopRuntime
}

distZip {
    into("$project.name/lib") {
        from configurations.desktopRuntime
    }
}
```

You can also solve the issue by using the `shadowJar`, providing you include the desktop dependencies, to create an executable fat jar, like in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709489/executable-jar-cant-find-or-load-main-class-after-its-created-with-a-gradle-ta/40718258#40718258).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try next steps:
```

1.

```
    dependencies {
      compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.15.1'
      runtime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.15.1'
    }
```

2. Go to "Files" tab in NetBeans IDE -> *your_project* -> *build* -> *libs* and here add your lib some as sqlite-jdbc.jar

Comment: my problem is we want android build and desktop build. this file  dont want to include in android build. this file must include in desktop only. Thankful.