# Gluon Desktop - Runnable jar

Tags: gluon, gluon-desktop

I am using the 'gradle distZip' command to build my desktop project, but when running the generated script I am having a security error, so Settings and other functions are not working, **but it works when using 'gradle run'**

```
`java.io.IOException: Private storage file not available
at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.c.a.c(SourceFile:37)
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.c.a.<clinit>(SourceFile:37)
at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.a(SourceFile:262)
at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.start(SourceFile:232)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)`
```

How to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: The stacktrace seems to be from Gluon Mobile. Are you sure its a Gluon Desktop application?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41041335/3956070)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha this is a Mobile/Desktop app, thank you!

Comment: Thank you @JoséPereda, this solved the problem!