# How to export a .jar file from a gluon project?

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

any idea how to export a .jar that includes everything from the gluon project ?
I used the Shadow jar but the result won't open and gives

```
    Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/converters/SizeConverter
        at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar.<clinit>(SourceFile:406)
        at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.start(SourceFile:191)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.converters.SizeConverter
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Are you running Java 9? The dependencies of your project (i.e Charm 4.4.1) are only for Java 8

Comment: so this jar file can only run on pcs with java 8 right ?

Comment: Yes, it required Java 8. Alternatively, you could use the Java 9 dependencies (charm:4.4.0-jdk9).

Comment: Thanks it worked ! you are really so helpful. I am grateful

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked. I'll post it as an answer, as it probably others will face the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export a jar of a Gluon project so it runs on desktop, you can use a Shadow [plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709489/executable-jar-cant-find-or-load-main-class-after-its-created-with-a-gradle-ta/40718258#40718258), or you can use the built-in tasks `jar` or `distZip, but taking into account that you need to modify the build to include the desktop dependencies, as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41035769/compile-and-build-gluon-mobile-app-for-desktop/41041335#41041335).

After that, the resulting jar will run on Java 8 or Java 9, based on what dependencies you were using.

So far, the regular jfxmobile plugin uses dependencies for Java 8:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.1'
}
```

So the resulting jar will run only under Java 8.

But you can modify the build so you can run Java 9 on Desktop:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.0-jdk9'
}
```

Note that if you have other dependencies, those should be compatible with Java 9 as well.